# "private space" or "private domain"?

Tags: word-choice

What would be a better name for somebody's personal sphere of life (e.g. close people, partners) - "**private domain**" or "**private space**"? I think the option with "**domain**" fits better in the context of people, but wanted to check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Private domain" is a better fit for the figurative sense you are going for. "Private space" would refer to an actual, physical space.

You could also use "private life" to convey the personal side of one's life, and the people that are a part of it.